# Arrange sequences of entries in pairs in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given a table of the form:

```
ID    Sequence
1     A,C,D,E,F,G
2     D,F,G,B
3     A,B,A,C
and so on
```

Now I wish to arrange this data so that it can be fed into a RNN in a sequential manner so that I'm able to predict the next entry in each sequence. So here's what's required (in a new dataframe) in the form of all possible sequences:

```
X        Y
A,C,D    E
C,D,E    F
D,E,F    G
D,F,G    B
A,B,A    C
```

X could be of length 3 or any custom length. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using `df.split` and applying `pd.Series` to sublists:

```
In [623]: df.Sequence.str.split(',')\
 ...:     .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x[i : i + 3], x[i + 3]] for i in range(0, len(x)- 3))).stack()\
 ...:     .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x[0], x[1]]))\
 ...:     .reset_index(drop=True)
Out[623]: 
           0  1
0  [A, C, D]  E
1  [C, D, E]  F
2  [D, E, F]  G
3  [D, F, G]  B
4  [A, B, A]  C
```

Setting the columns is as simple as `df.columns = ['X', 'Y']`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the (many) ways of doing it.

```
In [52]: vals = df.Sequence.str.split(',')

In [53]: seqs = []

In [54]: for val in vals:
    ...:     seqs += [{'X': val[i:i+3], 'Y': val[i+3]} for i in xrange(len(val)-3)]
    ...:

In [55]: pd.DataFrame(seqs)
Out[55]:
           X  Y
0  [A, C, D]  E
1  [C, D, E]  F
2  [D, E, F]  G
3  [D, F, G]  B
4  [A, B, A]  C
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
vals=[l.split(',') for l in df.sequences.values]
X,Y=zip(*sum([[[','.join(el[i:i+3]),el[i+3]] for i in range(len(el)-3)] for el in vals],[]))
res=pd.DataFrame({'X':X,'Y':Y})
```

Then `res` is

```
       X    Y
0   A,C,D   E
1   C,D,E   F
2   D,E,F   G
3   D,F,G   B
4   A,B,A   C
```